# How do I put Toolbar, FrameLayout, BottomNavigationView in one activity?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-xml

This worked when I put everything in the main.xml, but when I moved components into a separate xml and used include, The bottomnavigationview was no longer at the bottom:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_details_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activity_user_details_fragment_container"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_details_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activity_user_details_bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_user_details_toolbar" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_details_bottom_navigation"
        layout="@layout/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is my toolbar.xml layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/SkoolarActionBar"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

**First the BottomNavigationView is overlapping with the Toolbar because the FrameLayout Constraints are not being recognized. Second I have no way of accessing toolbar because when I use include, it's including the entire AppBarLayout and not just the Toolbar**

Comment: Where did you define namespace: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`?

Answer (score 0):

When you adjust the layout parameters on an `include` tag, you need to also specify `layout_width` and `layout_height`.

https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Result:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_details_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_details_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activity_user_details_bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_user_details_toolbar" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_details_bottom_navigation"
        layout="@layout/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try out this, It will give you same result what you want :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_details_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activity_user_details_fragment_container"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_details_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activity_user_details_bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_user_details_toolbar" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_user_details_bottom_navigation"
        layout="@layout/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

       </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The nested viewgroups are unnecessary, it can be solved with the original constraint layout

Comment: ok i'm solving with original question code and update my answer @JohnLeehey

Comment: I solved & edited my code as question code, Please remove downvote @JohnLeehey